# CSS - How to make a div's padding not affect the positioning of the div below it

Tags: html, css

So I have two boxes:
https://jsfiddle.net/anaegm/trajtmgf/

My original intention was to make `box-1` expand its height from the top and bottom when you hovered over it (as opposed to just "growing down" by adding padding), so I added a negative margin-top under the :hover to achieve this effect, and it works.

The problem is that `box-2` below gets pushed down when you hover over `box-1`, and I need the second box to stay in its original position at all times. I tried adding a margin at the top of `box-2`, but this doesn't work. What are my options?

EDIT: Since I'm working with dynamic text for the actual page I'm doing, I'd rather not use a set height for a div container for `box-1`.

```css
#box-1 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e91d23;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#box-1:hover {
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#box-2 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1">
  Box 1
</div>
<div id="box-2">
  Box 2
</div>
```

Comment: How about setting absolute position to the elements? That way they elements will not interfere with each other

Comment: absolute position is kind of overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning.

```css
#box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e91d23;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#box-1:hover {
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1">
  Box 1
</div>
<div id="box-2">
  Box 2
</div>
```

I hope this was what you were trying achieve.

Comment: After your comment I had tried with absolute positioning but I had completely missed using the top attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. 

Answer (score 1):

I have a so solution for you but i think this is not dynamic. take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/trajtmgf/1/

```
#box-1:hover + #box-2{
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach without using positioning

```css
#box-1 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e91d23;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#box-1:hover {
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#box-2 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#avoid-margin-collapse {
  /* avoid margin collapse (e.g. with a border, a padding, position) */
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="avoid-margin-collapse">
<div id="box-1">
  Box 1
</div>
<div id="box-2">
  Box 2
</div>
</div>
```